# MS SQL transactional replication between SQL V11 and V12

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I'm trying to set up transactional replication between linked ms sql servers.  The publication data is running in SQL v 11.0 and I'm trying set up the subscriber on a new server running sql V12.0.  Using the wizard but I'm getting an error that the subscription is not a high enough version.  This doesn't make sense.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Publisher is MTSQL02 and Subscriber is MTSQL04

[image]

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL server managament studio 2012

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

Comment: The correct answer was sql management Studio 2014!  This worked, or at least I was able to add the subscription.  Thanks